# Problema ao usar o "frozen columns" no Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando o primefaces com `frozenColumns`, desta forma:

```xml
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var=.... scrollable="true" scrollWidth="800" frozenColumns="1">
```

Só que quando ele quebra a linha, a coluna frozen não acompanha, como nesta imagem:

[image: Veja aqui o exemplo]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: English please, it's the "official" language of StackOverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje I used a translator to try and assist the question. Hopefully this helps

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: please don't; the OP themselves must be able to communicate in English. They need to be able to respond to feedback, for example.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: if they cannot themselves provide an English question, there is no point in leaving the post open with a machine translation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank's for the feedback, I'll take that under advisement.